# Pushing docker-compose to azure registry

Tags: docker-compose, azure-container-registry

Blessings,

I've got a docker-compose.yml and I am trying to push it to Azure container registry but it skips the upload.

```
 # docker-compose.yml

 version: '3'
 services:
     proxy:
         image: nginx:1.17.3
         ports:
             - 80:80
             - 443:443
         volumes:
             # Mount the nginx folder with the configuration
             - ./nginx:/etc/nginx:ro
             # Mount the letsencrypt certificates
             - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt:ro

     fdp:
         image: fairdata/fairdatapoint:1.15
         volumes:
             - ./application.yml:/fdp/application.yml:ro

     fdp-client:
         image: fairdata/fairdatapoint-client:1.15
         environment:
             - FDP_HOST=fdp

     mongo:
         image: mongo:4.0.12
         ports:
           - "127.0.0.1:27017:27017"
         volumes:
             - ./mongo/data:/data/db

     blazegraph:
         image: metaphacts/blazegraph-basic:2.2.0-20160908.003514-6
         volumes:
             - ./blazegraph:/blazegraph-data
```

I know the above has to be edited according to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/tutorial-docker-compose)

But I couldn't quite understand how the changes should be applied and would need some guidance.

I've tried building successfully using `docker-compose up --build -d` then `docker-compose push` returns the the following

```
[+] Running 5/0
 - blazegraph Skipped                                                                                              0.0s
 - proxy Skipped                                                                                                   0.0s
 - fdp Skipped                                                                                                     0.0s
 - fdp-client Skipped                                                                                              0.0s
 - mongo Skipped
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had to add a dockerfile and change the following inside my docker-compose

```
app:
         build: .
         image: foo.azurecr.io/foo
         container_name: foo
```

Prefix should be used when trying to push to ACR.

Dockerfile was just a simple python application installing dependencies, It is required to push so It was kept basic.